# can an IF function not work if it's format is in minutes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the formula `=IF(E17>=480,(E17/480),"Under 8 Hours")` which is meant to compute any value above 480, which is 8hrs in minutes.

But it's not working as it should. It's executing the formula even for values below 480. I've formatted the result cell as `d` "day(s)", `h` "hour(s)" and `m` "minute(s)" while the source cell (E17) is in minutes, `m`.

Comment: 8 hours is 0.333 days in Excel

Comment: Formatting doesn't affect in any way the real "value" of the cell, so is therefor not relevant to the formula. Can you share the example of what you type in (or what you see when editing the cell) into `E17`?

Comment: Look at the **underlying column value**. Calendar days are stored as a number, with 1.0 = one 24-hour day. Be aware of any hidden math that's **displaying** one day as 24 hours or 1,440 minutes or 86,400 seconds.

Comment: `=IF(HOUR(E17)>7;INT(E17)&" day(s), "&TEXT(E17;"H"" hour(s) and ""M"" minute(s)""");"Under 8 Hours")` ?

Comment: You can see what number is in `E7` with `=VALUE(E17)`.  I'm sure that will shed a lot of light, as that is what the if condition is working with as well.